# PHP error outputting erasing part of my html layout

Tags: php, forms

I borrowed this code from how to do a PHP emailer.   However, rather than theirs, which was here:  http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php  I decided to use `$PHP_SELF` and do it all in one file.

However, with the error outputting, it was removing my Contact Us thing, table, and footer stuff.

So I thought, must be a dang glitch, I'll just echo out the stuff in the Contact Us, table, and footer and put the error message in between the end of the table and the footer.

However, much to my annoyance, it is STILL erasing it and acting like my new stuff isn't even there.   Why is that and what can I do to fix it?  Am I better off using two separate files like they did?  (I didn't like their approach because there never was a back button once they either entered it right or even if they entered it wrong. )

Even stranger, if I do get it right and doesn't do the error messages, it does output all that stuff above, though way at the bottom and not in the place of the form and form that I had originally.

Finally, when I check my email (I know I have something else above, but in my main one, I use my email address, and also put it it in the from box too.  However, it's not showing up in my mailbox.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Contact Us </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="./ski_icon.png">
        <script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#container").css("height", 1135);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            form {
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="./logo.png"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <nav id="hor">
                    <div><a href="index.html"> Home </a> </div>
                    <div><a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a></div>
                    <div><a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a></div>
                    <div><a href="snowreports.html"> Snow Reports </a></div>
                    <div><a href="eventsandactivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a></div>
                    <div><a href="plantrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a></div>
                </nav>
                <div id="middle">
                    <nav id="vert">
                        <a href="index.html"> Home </a> <br/>
                        <a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a><br/>
                        <a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a><br/>
                        <a href="snowreports.html"> Snow Reports </a><br/>
                        <a href="eventsandactivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a><br/>
                        <a href="plantrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a>
                    </nav>    
                    <style>
                        td {
                            vertical-align: top;
                        }
                    </style>    
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
                            // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
                            $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
                            $email_subject = "Your email subject line";
                            function died($error) {
                                // your error code can go here
                                echo "<div id='text-container'>" ;
                                    echo "<h1>Contact Us</h1>";
                                    echo "<form name='contactform' method='post' action='$_PHP_SELF'>";
                                        echo"<table width='450px'>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo" <td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<label for='first_name'>First Name *</label>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                                echo " <td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo" <input  type='text' name='first_name' maxlength='50' size='30'>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo"<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<label for='last_name'>Last Name *</label>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<input  type='text' name='last_name' maxlength='50' size='30'>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<label for='email'>Email Address *</label>";     
                                                echo "</td>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<input  type='text' name='email' maxlength='80' size='30'>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<label for='telephone'>Telephone Number</label>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<input  type='text' name='telephone' maxlength='30' size='30'>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";     
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo  "<label for='comments'>Comments *</label>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                                echo "<td valign='top'>";
                                                    echo "<textarea  name='comments' maxlength='1000' cols='25' rows='6'></textarea>";
                                                echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>";
                                                    echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>   <a href='http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php'>Email Form</a>";     
                                                echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        echo "</table>";
                                    echo "</form>";
                                    echo "Bla bla bla";
                                    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
                                    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";      
                                    echo $error."<br /><br />";
                                    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
                                echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div id='footercontainer'>";
                            echo "<footer>";
                                echo "Copyright  &copy;  2016   Dimaond Peaks Resort, &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.  <br/>";
                                echo "<a href='http://www.allwebpromotion.com/' target='_blank'>Website Design</a> by: All Web Promotion";
                            echo "</footer>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
                // validation expected data exists
               if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['comments'])) 
               {
                   died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
               }
               $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
               $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
               $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
               $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
               $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
               $error_message = "";
               $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
               if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
                   $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
               }
               $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
               if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
                   $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
               }
               if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
                   $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
               }
               if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
                   $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
               }
               if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
                   died($error_message);
               }
               $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
               function clean_string($string) {
                   $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                   return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
               }
               $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
               $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
               $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
               $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
               $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
               // create email headers
               $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
                      'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
                      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
               @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
           ?>
           <!-- include your own success html here -->
           Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
           <?php } ?>
           <div id="text-container">
               <h1>Contact Us</h1>
               <form name="contactform" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                   <table width="450px">
                       <tr>
                           <td valign="top">
                               <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
                           </td>
                           <td valign="top">
                               <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td valign="top"">
                               <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
                           </td>
                           <td valign="top">
                               <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td valign="top">
                               <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
                           </td>
                           <td valign="top">
                               <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
                           </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
                          </td>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
                          </td>
                          <td valign="top">
                              <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                              <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footercontainer">
        <footer>Copyright  &copy;  2016   Dimaond Peaks Resort, &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.  <br/><a href="http://www.allwebpromotion.com/" target="_blank">Website Design</a> by: All Web Promotion</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.


Please go back and fix these errors.

Comment: That is not the issue.  The issue is that I want it to just add that message below the form, not overwrite the form and the footer below it.    Furthermore, if it gets it right, it still is putting everything at the bottom, so to speak, not in the spot where the form was.    And, lastly, I'm never seeing the message in my email box.

Comment: It would be shorter to toubleshoot it by looking at the HTML and JavaScript code that produce the error than the PHP code that generates them.  I suspect running the HTML code in a validator will point you in the right direction.

Comment: No.  No.  No.    The HTML and all is working fine.   It's not that kind of error.     It's the output of died() that is doing this.

Comment: The output of died() is overwriting my HTML form and my footer below.    What I want it to do is basically just put the output of died() in between the form and the footer.    Originally, I just had the stuff with the "We are sorry..." as the only output of died(), but thought if I outputted the other stuff, maybe it would come back.   But it hasn't.

Comment: Look at your `died()` function and tell me how it can be surprising that the regular footer is messed up if it gets written in `died()` and then later, and it doesn't even die.  Look at the full HTML when you have the error message and you'll see how obvious it becomes.  Now stop arguing and start searching.  If you really want help, show us the full HTML output with the error.

Comment: It was overwriting it already so I told it to be written again, thinking it was lost.   Also, originally it DID die, but I took out die() as I heard that was bad form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is your `nice` and fixed code =)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Contact Us </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<link rel="icon" href="./ski_icon.png">
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#container").css("height", 1135);


  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>


<style>

form
{
border: 1px solid transparent;
text-align: center;

}
</style>

<div id="content">
<div id="logo">
<img src="./logo.png"></img>
</div>
<div id="container">
<nav id="hor">
<div><a href="index.html"> Home </a> </div>
<div><a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a></div>
<div><a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a></div>
<div><a href="snowreports.html"> Snow Reports </a></div>
<div><a href="eventsandactivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a></div>
<div><a href="plantrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a></div>
</nav>
<div id="middle">
<nav id="vert">
<a href="index.html"> Home </a> <br/>
<a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a><br/>
<a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a><br/>
<a href="snowreports.html"> Snow Reports </a><br/>
<a href="eventsandactivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a><br/>
<a href="plantrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a>
</nav>

<style>

td
{

vertical-align: top;
}

</style>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here



       echo "<div id='text-container'>" ;

echo "<h1>Contact Us</h1>";

echo "<form name='contactform' method='post' action='$_PHP_SELF'>";

echo"<table width='450px'>";

echo "<tr>";

echo" <td valign='top'>";

  echo "<label for='first_name'>First Name *</label>";

 echo "</td>";

echo " <td valign='top'>";

 echo" <input  type='text' name='first_name' maxlength='50' size='30' value='".(isset($_POST['first_name'])?$_POST['first_name']:'')."' >";

 echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

 echo"<td valign='top'>";

  echo "<label for='last_name'>Last Name *</label>";

 echo "</td>";

 echo "<td valign='top'>";

  echo "<input  type='text' name='last_name' maxlength='50' size='30'  value='".(isset($_POST['last_name'])?$_POST['last_name']:'')."' >";

 echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td valign='top'>";

echo "<label for='email'>Email Address *</label>";

echo "</td>";

 echo "<td valign='top'>";

 echo "<input  type='text' name='email' maxlength='80' size='30'   value='".(isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'')."'  >";

 echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td valign='top'>";

 echo "<label for='telephone'>Telephone Number</label>";

echo "</td>";

echo "<td valign='top'>";

echo "<input  type='text' name='telephone' maxlength='30' size='30'     value='".(isset($_POST['telephone'])?$_POST['telephone']:'')."'   >";

echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td valign='top'>";

echo  "<label for='comments'>Comments *</label>";

echo "</td>";

echo "<td valign='top'>";

 echo "<textarea  name='comments' maxlength='1000' cols='25' rows='6'> ".(isset($_POST['comments'])?$_POST['comments']:'')."  </textarea>";

echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>";

  echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>   <a href='http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php'>Email Form</a>";

 echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

echo "</form>";

echo "Bla bla bla";

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";


      echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='footercontainer'>";
echo "<footer>";
 echo "Copyright  &copy;  2016   Dimaond Peaks Resort, &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.  <br/>";
echo "<a href='http://www.allwebpromotion.com/' target='_blank'>Website Design</a> by: All Web Promotion";

echo "</footer>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
exit;
?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>




<div id="text-container">

<h1>Contact Us</h1>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top"">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>



  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footercontainer">
<footer>
 Copyright  &copy;  2016   Dimaond Peaks Resort, &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.  <br/>
<a href="http://www.allwebpromotion.com/" target="_blank">Website Design</a> by: All Web Promotion

</footer>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of your died() function contains the same contact form that you are shown below, restructure your code a little bit.

get rid of the form in died() function

```
    function died($error) {

        echo "Bla bla bla";

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    }
```

after show the validation errors show a Go Back button and the form if you want

```
   <!-- include your own success html here -->
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<a href="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">Go Back</a>

<?php

}


// get rid or comment this condition if want show form with the errors messages  
if (!$error_message) {

?>


<div id="text-container">

<h1>Contact Us</h1>
```

the form ...

```
<?php 
    }
?>
```